# I get a GraphQL error when running this query using the apollo server. Anyone one knows what is the problem with it?

Tags: graphql, angular7

I am trying to fetch some data from the GitHub GraphQL but I get a GaphQLError. I have tried the same query on the developer section of github and it works. Anyone know what is the problem with it?

```
issueQuery = gql`
        query search(first: 10, type: ISSUE, query: "repo:angular/angular is:issue state:open") {
          issueCount
          edges {
            node {
              ... on Issue {
                createdAt
                title
                body
                url
                comments(first: 10) {
                  nodes {
                    body
                  }
                }
              }
            }
          }
        }
      `;
```

Error Stack Trace:

```
"GraphQLError: Syntax Error: Expected $, found Name "first"
    at syntaxError (http://localhost:4200/vendor.js:70270:10)
    at expect (http://localhost:4200/vendor.js:75154:67)
    at parseVariable (http://localhost:4200/vendor.js:73984:3)
    at parseVariableDefinition (http://localhost:4200/vendor.js:73970:15)
    at many (http://localhost:4200/vendor.js:75222:16)
    at parseVariableDefinitions (http://localhost:4200/vendor.js:73959:82)
    at parseOperationDefinition (http://localhost:4200/vendor.js:73926:26)
    at parseExecutableDefinition (http://localhost:4200/vendor.js:73881:16)
    at parseDefinition (http://localhost:4200/vendor.js:73845:16)
    at many (http://localhost:4200/vendor.js:75222:16)"
```

New Error Stack Trace when adding $ before the parameters:

```
"GraphQLError: Syntax Error: Expected Name, found Int "10"
    at syntaxError (http://localhost:4200/vendor.js:70270:10)
    at expect (http://localhost:4200/vendor.js:75154:67)
    at parseName (http://localhost:4200/vendor.js:73809:15)
    at parseNamedType (http://localhost:4200/vendor.js:74385:11)
    at parseTypeReference (http://localhost:4200/vendor.js:74364:12)
    at parseVariableDefinition (http://localhost:4200/vendor.js:73971:83)
    at many (http://localhost:4200/vendor.js:75222:16)
    at parseVariableDefinitions (http://localhost:4200/vendor.js:73959:82)
    at parseOperationDefinition (http://localhost:4200/vendor.js:73926:26)
    at parseExecutableDefinition (http://localhost:4200/vendor.js:73881:16)"
```

Comment: What is the error?

Comment: I've added the error stack trace.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Don't confuse the operation with the actual field being queried. The syntax should look like this:

```
operationType [operationName] [variableDefinitions] {
  selectionSet
}
```

where `operationType` is one of `query`, `mutation` or `subscription`, `operationName` is an arbitrary name for your operation used in debugging, `variableDefinitions` are type definitions for any variables you reference inside the operation, and `selectionSet` is one or more fields you're actually querying.

In this case, `search` is a field we're querying, so it should not be proceeded by the `query` keyword. This works fine, provided you're authenticated:

```
query OptionalName {
  search(first: 10, type: ISSUE, query: "repo:angular/angular is:issue state:open") {
    issueCount
    edges {
      # more fields
    }
  }
}
```

If the operation type is `query`, you can omit the `query` keyword altogether. This is called "query shorthand":

```
{
  search(first: 10, type: ISSUE, query: "repo:angular/angular is:issue state:open") {
    issueCount
    edges {
      # more fields
    }
  }
}
```

If you use variables, define them inside parentheses beside your operation. Variable names are arbitrary, but by convention we use the input field names they will be used in:

```
query OptionalName ($first: Int, type: SearchType!, $query: String! ) {
  search(first: $first, type: $type, query: $query) {
    issueCount
    edges {
      # more fields
    }
  }
}
```